Fourier transform of error function
Is there already a method in the literature to calculate the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{erf}^{\,s}\left(x\right)$ with $s \in \mathbb{C}$?
Thanks!

Hello. Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please read about how to ask a good question and improve your question by showing your work or effort.

It isn’t a work

@DuongNgo my curiosity

I meant, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

@DuongNgo
I wanted to understand if it is possible to calculate it or if the Fourier transform of this function already exists

@DuongNgo i’ve modify the question. I hope now it’s better

We can take the Fourier transform of the error function within distribution theory. I will here skip factors, so the equal signs should only be interpreted as "modulo factors that don't affect the principle".
We have $e^{-x^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{erf}(x).$ Taking the Fourier transform of both sides gives
$$
e^{-\xi^2} = \mathcal{F}\{e^{-x^2}\} = \mathcal{F}\{\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{erf}(x)\} = i\xi \mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{erf}(x)\}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{erf}(x)\} = \operatorname{pv}\frac{e^{-\xi^2}}{i\xi} + C\delta(\xi)
$$
for some constant $C.$ Here $\operatorname{pv}$ stands for principal value and means that integration of $\frac{e^{-\xi^2}}{i\xi}$ is done over $|\xi|>\epsilon$ and then letting $\epsilon\to 0.$
For $\operatorname{erf}(x)^n$ we can then use the convolution theorem to conclude that (again modulo factors) that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{erf}(x)^n\} 
= \left( \operatorname{pv}\frac{e^{-\xi^2}}{i\xi} + C\delta(\xi) \right)^{n*},
$$
where
$$
u(\xi)^{n*} = \underbrace{u*\cdots*u}_{\text{$n$ factors}}(\xi).
$$
I'm not certain that this convolution is well-defined, though. There are problems with convolutions of distributions that do not have compact support.

but your formulation is only valid when “n” is an integer, or am i wrong? How can i use the convolutiom theorem for calcilate the fourier transform of erf(x)^i for example?

Oh, I just saw $n$ and not that it could be complex. Well, at least you have an answer for the $n\in\mathbb N$ case.

thank you so much!

By the way, what is your definition of the error function? The one on Wikipedia is negative for $x<0$ so non-integer powers are problematic.

i think that a powers of erf(x) will be a function with a complex codomain

Is the constant not just $0$? Formally taking the integral over $\mathbb R$ seems to give that at least

@LL3.14. You are correct. The error function is odd, the pv term is odd, so the $\delta$ term must also be odd. But it's even unless it vanishes. Thus $C=0.$

@md2perpe the question is closed… so it’s impossible calculate a complex power of erf(x)?

Complex powers are strange; there are many values to choose from.

It just so happened that Michael Penn posted a video about non-integer powers of complex numbers. Complex powers are as strange.

@md2perpe Ok, it’s clear, I’ll settle for integer powers greater than 1.
